# Sorting range in ascending numerical order containing strings by vba excel

Tags: sorting, excel, range, vba

i have a range containing the following strings:

step_1, step_10, step_3, step_2

using the following code

```
input_sh.Activate
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("H2:H20").Select
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H2"), _
       SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers 'xlSortNormal
With .Sort
        .SetRange Range("H2:H20")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
End With
```

step_10, step_1, step_2, step_3

but i would like to get

step_1, step_2,step_3,step_10

Comment: You would need to write a custom sorting algorithm. It depends how generic you wish this to be - is there a good reason that you cannot simply change the `String` values to `Step_01` etc.

Comment: I have tried to change the strings as you are suggesting but I get the same result.

Comment: the string are filenames extracted from a specific directory, so i cannot modify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate the number into another column, your last + 1, using mid function and sort on that.

---

Edit: I'm not at my pc but I think your only way to do this is to setup a macro that:

1. Filter your sheet by the first 9.
2. Cut and insert them before row 2.
3. Sort these on their own.
4. Then remove the filter and sort the rest as you have above.

Comment: to glh I thought of doing that, but I hoped I would not have to come down to that.

Comment: Are you able to override the the values there or are they required in this format?

Comment: they are file names, from a folder. they have to be in that format

Answer (score 0):

Your strings have underscore followed by numbers. if that is going to be format of your string you can simply split your string using convert text to columns using "_" as your delimiter. Later you can sort and concatenate to get your sorted list of strings.

[image]

```
 Sub Sample()


        Columns(1).Copy Columns(3)

        Columns("C:C").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Other:=True, OtherChar:="_", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))

        Columns("D:D").Sort Range("D1")

        i = 1
        Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("C" & i))
            Range("B" & i) = Range("C" & i) & "_" & Range("D" & i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks every one for you contribution.
to user I found my solution before reading your suggestion. thanks anyway for your effort

my solution:

- split str for "_"
- write 2nd index next to filenames order 2nd cols by then col with only number
- clean col with numbers

Comment: As i suspected what was needed... ;)